# Put a div:s content in a variable and use substring to show part of content in textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I'm having this jQuery-function witch takes the content from a div and puts the content of it in a textbox when clicking on the div.

JQuery:

```
$('.table-time').click(function () {

    $('input#Time').val($(this).html());

})
```

But I'm only want to show part of the content in the textbox.
For example, the div:s content is: "08:00 - 09:30", but I'm only want to show: "08:00" in the textbox.
I'm trying to figure it out by putting the div:s content in a variable in my function and then use substring with it, but I don't know how. Don't even know if it's the right way to do it...

Html, c# in razor mvc:

```
foreach (var item in Model.LedigaTider)
{
<div class="table-time" id="@item.ToShortTimeString()" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupEventForm');">
@item.ToShortTimeString() - @item.AddMinutes(ViewBag.BehTid).ToShortTimeString()
</div>
}
```

Comment: $('input#Time').val($(this).html().split(':')[0]); is what you want?

Comment: Yes @juvian ! It's exactly what I was looking for :) Works perfect. Note: the split is going to be made where the '-' character is. But the code you gave me works of course perfect for that to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use substring, but I think it is easier with `split` :

```
var str = $.trim($(this).text().split('-')[0]);
$('input#Time').val(str);
```

- Trim will remove to whitespace from the new value;
- text will get the text and not the html. Change nothing in your example, but i prefer using text so you have no problems with HTML entities;
- Split will transform you string into an array. every time it encounter `-`, it make a new cell. The final array is `['   08:00 ', ' 09:30     ']`;
- `[0]` select the first cell of that array.